# Web Api Versioning for multi tenant saas application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, multi-tenant, saas

I currently developing a multi tenant saas application using asp web api. The api will be published and consumed by 3rd party application. My question is regarding versioning. I'm struggling to find a way to build the api so that when i updated the api, it wont make 3rd party app that uses the api to stop working. I've seen many api append the version no into the url. But that means that i have to keep old version api until all 3rd party app has been upgraded and use the latest api. I also have to update the old api to adapt to database change. That seems like a lot of work. How do big companies solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way around this; you will have to do the work to support old versions as long as your customers are using them.

Adopting a RESTful approach in the first place, and avoiding 'fat controllers' may help reduce the pain but beyond that every old API call will need to call into your new service layer and will need to return the results in the format your clients expect.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I guess i have to make the controller as thin as possible, and limit the support to the api only for certain time.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm struggling to find a way to build the api so that when i updated the api, it wont make 3rd party app that uses the api to stop working. I've seen many api append the version no into the url. But that means that i have to keep old version api until all 3rd party app has been upgraded and use the latest api.

No one, absolutely no one has researched, built, versioned and maintained APIs more than NetFlix - not externally but internally. They used explicit versioning (e.g. URL) in their APIs and maintained multiple versions of the same API and got their clients move along by providing incentives (new features). This is also something that can be built into your SLA, e.g. you guarantee support of particular version only for 12 months.

This is a very controversial topic and you will hear people suggesting implicit versioning (e.g. by media type etc). Feel free to listen to those but pragmatism favours explicit and purism favours implicit.